# Group By and Aggregate Summary Statistics in Same Data.Table

Tags: r, data.table

I am collapsing a table of data to a table of summary statistics.  In the main, I want to do it "by" a particular factor variable, but I also want to summarize without "by", over all values.  Consider:

```
dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(216),72),dim1=c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),rep("C",24)))
dt0 <- dt[,list(mean=mean(V1)), by=list(dim1)]
dt1 <- dt[,list(mean=mean(V1), dim1=NA)]
dt <- rbind(dt0, dt1)
```

The result would be:

```
dim1 mean
A    n.nn
B    m.mm
C    o.oo
NA   p.pp
```

Is there a beautiful, concise way to do this, without creating the temporary data.tables or manually handling the NA?

Comment: It's usually possible to avoid creating temporary objects by stringing commands together (as seen in akrun's answer). You can avoid multiple `dt[i,j]` calls by doing more in `j`, but I don't know about getting around manual handling of the NA/all case: `dt[,{ x<-tapply(V1,dim1,mean); list(dim1=c(x,mean(V1)),mean=c(names(x),"all")) }]`. By the way, you reused the variable name `dt`, which is confusing, as is the creation of superfluous variables V2 and V3; and finally, it's preferable to use `set.seed` when creating random data, so we're all looking at the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `rbindlist` with `fill=TRUE` after placing the `mean` subsets in a `list`

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
rbindlist(list(dt[,list(Mean=mean(V1)), by=dim1],
                  dt[, list(Mean=mean(V1))]), fill=TRUE)
#   dim1        Mean
#1:    A -0.13769807
#2:    B -0.27886124
#3:    C  0.13357025
#4:   NA -0.09432969
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
dt <- data.table(matrix(rnorm(216),72),dim1=c(rep("A",24),rep("B",24),
 rep("C",24)))
```